# Overriding croak cluck confess carp from carp module in Perl

Tags: perl, die, overriding, carp

I know how to override in built functions in `perl` and I have overridden `die` `warn` `say` and since `print` and `printf` can't be overridden I have tied it to a handle for my logging framework.

**Example of overriding `warn`:**

```
BEGIN{ *CORE::GLOBAL::warn = sub {
                my ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine) = caller;
                untie *STDERR;
                my $message;
                foreach my $arg (@_) {
                        $message = $message.$arg;
                }
                print STDERR $message;
                tie *STDERR, __PACKAGE__, (*STDERR);
                logmessage("warn",$message,$filename, $line);
                return;
        }
}
```

Now is there way I can override `croak cluck confess carp` from `carp` module in `Perl`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions provided by Carp are just regular functions that get imported into your packages via Exporter when the module is `use`d. The trick is to overwrite them as early as possible *inside of the `Carp` namespace*, before anyone can import them. Then when they do, they'll get the overwritten ones.

In your  script, or at the very top of your own logging module:

```
BEGIN {
    require Carp;

    # save original croak (will create closure ...)
    my $original_croak = \&Carp::croak;

    no warnings 'redefine';
    *Carp::croak = sub { 
        print "Croaking...\n"
          or $original_croak->("cannot fake croak"); # (... here)
    };
}
```

You need to load Carp once so Perl has the code parsed and the functions installed in the `Carp` namespace. Then you can overwrite them.

Later, in some other module in your code:

```
use Carp 'croak';

croak 'foo';
```

This will now produce the output we set above.

If you want to call the original `Carp::croak` inside your new one, save it to a coderef and keep it around as shown in the above example.

Note that this only works if the substitution happens really early. If you put this in your own logging module, and it gets loaded after Carp has been loaded, this will fail.

```
package Foo;
use Carp;
use Your::Logging::Framework;

croak 'foo';
```

Will not work, because at the point where you overwrite `Carp::croak`, `Foo::croak` is already a copy of the original `Carp::croak`.

If you wanted to make that work, you could always import your own `carp`, `croak` and so on to the caller explicitly as well. That will throw a bunch of warnings or complain under `strict`, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks since i am setting env{PERL5OPT}= "-MMyLoggingModule" i should work. I have one more question can i call the actual croak inside my overriden croak?

Comment: @DineshGowda I thought I addressed that. Looks like I didn't. You need to save the original one, e.g. into a variable. I'll edit.